# Terraform resource for AWS S3 Batch Operation

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I couldn't find Terraform resource for AWS S3 batch operation? I was able to create AWS s3 inventory file through terraform but couldn't create an s3 batch operation.

Did anyone create the s3 batch opearion through terraform?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no Terraform resource for an S3 batch operation. In general, most Terraform providers only have resources for things that are actually resources (they hang around), not things that could be considered "tasks". For the same reason, there's no CloudFormation resource for S3 batch operations either.

Your best bet is to use a module that allows you to run shell commands and use the AWS CLI for it. I like to use [this module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Invicton-Labs/shell-resource/external/latest) for these kinds of tasks. You would use it in combination with the [AWS CLI command for S3 batch jobs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3control/create-job.html).